Maintain position in terminal command history on macOS?
I enter many commands into the terminal.  I enter command a, then b, then c, etc.  I'm on command g now but I want to execute a, then b, then c, again.
I press up (g), up (f), up (e), up (d), up (c), up (b), up (a), then enter to execute a.  I have to press up 7 times again to get to and execute b.  Same for c.
On Windows, I maintain my position in the command history.  So once I get to command a and press enter, I just press up maybe twice to get to b, and maybe twice again to get to c.  This makes repeating sequences easier, obviously.  The terminal apparently stays at its HEAD position, relative to history.
How can the macOS terminal be reconfigured to maintain its position in the command history?

Won't it be easier to find your command using 'bck-i-search' ?

Not from the perspective of ease and overall keystrokes to repeat the same sequence of commands.

Valid, don't think there is a way to let history act like that. I've always used the number with ! from history, and then keep incrementing that. So if (a) is !10, run that, then !11, !12 etc...

Just to be clear, are you really using bash, or are you using zsh (which is the default shell on macOS)?

Maybe zsh. Yes, the default terminal.

I added an answer for bash. As this isn't really a programming question, though, you should probably ask at either unix.stackexchange.com or apple.stackexchange.com. (I think my answer applies to zsh as well, but there seems to be a slight difference that I haven't been able to pinpoint yet.)

Relocated to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775468/maintain-position-in-terminal-command-history-on-macos.

So they did this in Windows too? I implemented this as a feature in the interactive listener of the TXR Lisp programming language. If you hit Enter,  then it behaves in the traditional way like the shells. To maintain position (actually: to the next command in sequence at the history position), you can use Ctrl-X Enter.  The need for this is totally obvious: you need to repeat a 5 command sequence that is 100 commands back; searching back for each one is a non-starter.

The up-arrow can be preceded by a count to indicate how many commands back you want to go. How you do that depends on whether you use emacs or vi bindings, but I'll assume you are using the default emacs bindings.
To go back 7 commands, press Escape, then 7, then ⇧. If you wanted to go back 10 or more times, press Escape before each digit in the count. (For example, to go back 13 commands, press Escape 1 Escape 3 ⇧.)

Isn't the question "How can the macOS terminal be reconfigured to maintain its position in the command history?"? Your answer does not seem to answer that...

This provides an alternative, but you are correct is not the most desirable approach/answer.  It may be that the terminal simply can't do what's been asked of it.

Not directly, but I think it accomplishes a similar purpose (decreasing the number of keystrokes to repeat commands a, b, and c. History substitution would probably be even more useful, as it would allow all three commands to be executed as a group

You might also want to look at the fc command. fc -e - -7 - 5 should execute a, b, and c directly.

History search is controlled by the shell, and has nothing to do with the terminal emulator or the OS, beyond what’s installed by default.
If you like what your Windows system is doing, check the shell there (echo $0), its version, and history-related settings in the config files, and use the same setup on your Mac.
You don’t actually say what shell you’re using, but zsh can be configured to do pretty much anything.

echo $0 definitely doesn't work in the default shells in Windows (cmd and powershell)
